# How to have an absolute element within an element with display:contents

Tags: html, css

With CSS, I set `display:contents` on a Div, so that children of this Div can respect grid of the parent of this Div, but I Have one element within this Div with absolute positioning, which I want respecting the `position:relative` of the Div.

```html
<section style="display:grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0px, 1fr));height: 300px;width: 300px;background-color: red;">
  <div style="display:contents;position:relative;">
    <article style="background-color: blue;">1</article>
    <article style="background-color: black;">2</article>
    <span style="position: absolute;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;top: 0;background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);">
                 This should float on top of everything, but within the bounds of Div with `position relative`
            </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set your span as another grid item. Then you can ensure it overlaps by telling all 3 items to be on the same row (`grid-row: 1`), and by telling your text to span across both columns (`grid-column-start 1; grid-column-end: 3`).

By doing it this way you won't need the container div: the section tag is already containing all items so this seems more semantically correct for this example.

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0px, 1fr));
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.left-column {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right-column {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: black;
}

.span-columns {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="left-column">1</article>
  <article class="right-column">2</article>
  <span class="span-columns">
    This should float on top of everything, but within the bounds of Div with `position relative`
  </span>
</section>
```

Comment: there is no need to change span with div